# DIsplay image in imageview from local storage

Tags: listview, xamarin.android, imageview

I am developing one xamarin android app where i have implemented one listview. so i need to display that image  into listview so how to display image in imageview using path.

I am not getting how to display image from file path in xamarin.android

Here my CustomAdaptor

```
internal class MyCustomListAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    private List<AlbumTable> albm;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Context c;
    Dialog dialog;
    public MyCustomListAdapter(Context c,List<AlbumTable> albm)
    {
        this.albm = albm;
        this.c = c;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)c.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);

    }

    public override int Count
    {

        get
        {
            return albm.Count();
        }
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return long.Parse(albm[position].Id);
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        Button btnDelete;

        ViewHolder1 holder = null;
        if (view == null)
        {
            view = mInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.inflate_album, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder1();
            holder.coverp = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.sliderviewpager);
            btnDelete = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.share_album);
            btnDelete.Focusable = false;
            btnDelete.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
            btnDelete.Clickable = true;
            btnDelete.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {

                Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder alert = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(c);
                alert.SetTitle("Delete Album");
                alert.SetMessage("Are you really wnt to delete the Album");
                alert.SetCancelable(false);
                alert.SetPositiveButton("Yes", delegate {
                    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper();
                    bool aa=db.DeleteFromTable(albm[position]);

                    if (aa)
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(c, "Album Deleted Successfully", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    }
                });
                alert.SetNegativeButton("No", delegate {
                    if (dialog.IsShowing)
                        dialog.Dismiss();
                });
                dialog = alert.Create();
                dialog.Show();

            };
        }
        else
        {
            btnDelete = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.share_album);
            holder = view.Tag as ViewHolder1;
            btnDelete.Tag = position;

        }

        return view;
    }
```

and my getter setter methods are as follows

```
class AlbumTable
{

    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string ZipFillPath { get; set; }

    public string CoverPhotoPath { get; set; }

    public string AlbumKey { get; set; }

    public string NoOfPages { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    public string ZipPostalCode { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

}

How to display the image in imageview using path.

Answer (score 0):

> How to display the image in imageview using path.

There are some third-party library which implements this feature quite well like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glide.Xamarin/).

For Picasso, there is official document shows how to use it in Xamarin.Android project: [Binding a .JAR](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/).

Then you can code for example like this:

```
Picasso.With(this).Load(imageUrl).Into(imageView);
```